# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a project to upload an Excel file and then view it on the page to continue editing using vb.net ... according to this code

```
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)


            'Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/") & "Clients" & "\"
            Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/") & Session("CustName") & "/Clients\"
            If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
                'If Directory (Folder) does not exists Create it.
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
            End If
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath & Regex.Replace(SQLHandleAps(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)), "[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+]", "") & Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName))
            Dim fileLocation As String = folderPath & Regex.Replace(SQLHandleAps(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)), "[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+]", "") & Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName)

            '     FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation)
            If fileExtension = ".xls" Then
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
                LblError.Visible = False
            ElseIf fileExtension = ".xlsx" Then
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
                LblError.Visible = False
            Else
                LblError.CssClass = "ErrorContent"
                LblError.Text = "Your file selected Not Excel file"
                LblError.Visible = True
                Exit Sub
            End If

            RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = True

            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
            Dim dAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dtExcelRecords As New DataTable()
            con.Open()
            Dim dtExcelSheetName As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            Dim getExcelSheetName As String = dtExcelSheetName.Rows(0)("Table_Name").ToString()
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM [" & getExcelSheetName & "]"
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords)
            Dim ExlRecord = dtExcelRecords.Rows
            con.Close()
            GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
```

it's working perfectly but when I Publish the project to the web I had this error

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Comment: Do you have the correct drivers installed on the server?

Comment: What is the target CPU of your project? Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/296080/how-to-fix-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-no

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy of the ACE database engine installed on that machine running the web site.

Furthermore, you need to match up the bit size of the access data engine. You don't mention if you running the site as x64 bits (default these days), or you want to force/set the app-pool to run as x32 bits.

So, while you don't need office/access installed, and you don't need to have even the access runtime installed? (both of which would work).

You can pick the most "light weight" install, and at the VERY least you need to install the ACE data engine.

Furthermore, do NOT use "any" CPU for your project, but make sure  you set it to run as x32 bits (if using x32 bit version of ACE), or to run as x64 bits, if you using x64 bit version of ace.

So, you need to deal with 2 issues:

Force your project to a given bit size. So,  do NOT use ANY cpu, but use x86 (for x32 bits Access/ACE), and use x64 for x64 bits Access/ACE.

So, while you could install office/access, or install the Access runtime, a BETTER choice is to install JUST the Access data engine (which is what access uses also).

You can find a copy of the ACE data engine here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Make sure you download + install the correct version (probably x64 bit version these days, since that's what your defaults for the IIS web server will be (x64 bits).

As noted, this also means you don't want to use "ANY cpu" for the project settings, but force the project to compile to x32 or x64 bits based on the current bit size of the Access Data Engine you installed (ACE).

Comment: Note that if you need to make a 64-bit app work with 32-bit Access engine, you can do that using cross-process COM with a 32-bit COM server to do the data access.